# Intellij Idea: debugging GWT client code

Tags: firefox, gwt, intellij-idea

I've read about the possibility to debug GWT client code directly in Intellij. Unfortunately, I can't find the extension for Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=intellij&appver=any&platform=all

gives no results. I have Firefox 35 on CentOS.

The plugin for Chromium doesn't seem to work at all. It was installed successfully, but when I try to debug a new tab is open:

[chrome-extension://hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/loading.html?url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8888%2Fevents.html](http://chrome-extension://hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/loading.html?url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8888%2Fevents.html)

which leads to empty html page.

P.S. I'm talking about debugging JS code in GWT 2.7.

Comment: Which gwt Version are you using? In GWT 2.7 and above there is the new Super Dev Mode. A complete different way to debug your gwt application. Have a look here: http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html

The browser plugins are deprecated since a few month.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways of debugging GWT code: **Dev Mode** and **Super Dev Mode**. The fist requires a special browser plugin indeed. But Dev Mode was deprecated since GWT 2.6. It's recommended to use Super Dev Mode since GWT 2.6 which doesn't require any browser plugins.

Comment: Hi, I added P.S. to my question. I'm interested in debugging js code, but instead of browser I want to use Intellij. I use super dev mode.

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you want to debug JSNI code or pure JS?

Comment: As I've read here http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/intellij-idea-14-brings-better-gwts-super-dev-mode-support/  Intellij makes use of source maps and allows to debug your compiled Java code not in browser, but in Intellij. So I wanted to try it out